# Dynamic Input for Statistics

Tags: c, bash

Is there an equivalent solution similar to this implementation I've written in bash? Normally, I've always handled dynamic allocation like so:

(I like the second implementation because it's flexible and I don't need to know exactly how many inputs I need, I can input them as is. How can I accomplish a similar approach in C?

**C Implementation:**

```
double* get_data(int* data_size)
{
    double* data_set = NULL;
    int size = get_size();
    int i;

    *data_size = size;

    data_set = malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        printf("Enter statistical data: ");
        scanf("%lf", &data_set[i]);
    }

    return data_set;
}
```

**Bash Implementation:**

```
data_set=()
while IFS= read -r -p 'Enter statistical data (empty line to quit):' input; do
  [[ $input ]] || break
  data_set+=("$input")
done
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem here? The C implementation seems pretty fine.

Comment: You need a linked list or some other kind of dynamic allocator.  Then make a loop that gets the input, and add to the list each time.

Comment: @akluth It's fine, but I'd like to be able to input data continuously instead of having to prompt myself: "How many inputs?". Something along the lines of a  scanf inside of a while loop. I'm just stuck on how I would need to set it up.

Comment: Note that if you simply read to EOF, that often works well.  Not always, but often.  You should, in any case, handle early EOF so if the user types 100 as the number to enter and gets bored after 13 entries, your code copes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use C++. But that's not what you're asking, so I'll leave it there.

The following, although it looks awful at first glance, is actually usually pretty efficient (depending on your C library's implementation of `realloc`, but it's a common idiom in GNU code so the `realloc` implementation is usually well-adapted to it):

```
double* get_data(size_t *size_p) {
  size_t n = 0;
  double* data = NULL;
  double val;
  while (get_a_datum(&val)) {
    double* newdata = realloc(data, (n + 1) * sizeof *data);
    if (newdata == NULL) { free(data); report(error); }
    data = newdata;
    data[n++] = val;
  }
  if (size_p) *size_p = n;
  return data;
}
```

If you're not happy with that approach, you can roll your own exponential realloc, where you track the size of the allocated vector and, if it is about to be exceeded, double it. That's more code, though, and it's highly likely that `realloc` will do precisely that for you.

Comment: This looks like the direction I would need, thanks for the input! Also, what exactly is get_a_datum doing? Is this where your receiving the data?

Comment: @user520720: Yes, it's getting a datum :) See Jonathan Leffler's answer for why your current scanf is not ideal. Separating into a separate function feels cleaner to me: the idea is that it returns a boolean (success) and puts the result in the reference argument.

Comment: Something like `data=newdata` is missing.

Comment: @jofel: Oops, thanks. As to point 2, that was in my last paragraph all along. Was there something that made that difficult to understand?

Comment: @rici sorry, I missed what you wrote.

Comment: @rici One last question.. I'm not too familiar with size_t, how can I invoke this correctly? Normally I would call it like so: data = get_data(&data_size); In this case, you passed in size_t. Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @user520720: `size_t` is "some unsigned integer type" which is used as the size argument of `malloc`; it's also the value type of the `sizeof` operator. I probably confused you by calling the size_t* parameter `size_p`; in retrospect, the _p suffix (which I use for pointers) is more confusing than helpful. The only difference would be that in your calling routing, you would declare data_size as a `size_t` rather than an `int`, and it's entirely up to you whether you do it or not. (Google style guide says use int rather than size_t but I no longer work there so I've gone back to my old habits.)

Comment: I see, I really appreciate the help @rici maybe I'll port this over in c++ like you said to practice some more.

Comment: @user520720: If you do that, you'll find that the `std::vector` method `append` deals with all the memory management issues perfectly. Vectors know their own size, so you don't need two variables for one thing. And you don't even need to worry about memory leaks (if you return the vector rather than a pointer to a vector; in modern C++, returning vectors directly works just fine.)

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with `scanf("%lf", &data_set[i]);` is that `scanf()` skips leading white space, including blank lines, silently.

Since you want to terminate on an empty line, the obvious solution seems to be to use `fgets()` or `getline()` to read a line and then use `sscanf()` to read the data when the line is not empty.

Hence:

```
char line[4096];
while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
{
    if (line[0] == '\n')
        break;
    if (sscanf(line, "%lf", &data_set[i++]) != 1)
        ...format error...
}
```

Note that each I/O function is checked.  If you enter a blank or two on an otherwise empty line, they'll go into the 'format error' code.  You can make the test for 'blank line' more sensitive if you wish (consider using `strspn()` and `strlen()`, for example).

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know that about scanf(). This helped me out a lot, thank you.

Comment: Quick question, is there any reason in particular that line holds 4096?

Comment: No (there's no reason to think that line holds 4096).  However, the minimum value for LINE_MAX is _POSIX_LINE_MAX and that is 2048, so by using 4096, I'm more than accommodating what POSIX 'mandates'.  Basically, though, I use 4096 (rather than 80 or 256) for its shock value.  It doesn't cost much stack space on most machines (embedded is a different issue), but does mean you will seldom read text where the lines are longer than that (unless it is newline-less formatting like some JSON files).  So, I didn't bother to check that the whole line was read here, for example.

Comment: Got it! Just one last thing, I've got a working solution going, but now I'm refactoring it to terminate with an empty line. Once I've reallocated the array and error handled by checking to see if the array is null, at this point I usually assign data_set[size++] = input, whereas input is a double read in by scanf. With your example, I'm now reading input with line, but I can't assign line to a double*. Could you explain this more? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: After you've read the line, you can use `if (sscanf(line, "%lf", &data_set[i++]) != 1)` (as in my answer) to assign a double value extracted from the line, or you can do something else more fancy (`strtod()`, `atof()`, ...).  You can assign to a separate `double d` (e.g. passing `&d` to `sscanf()`) and then use `data_set[i++] = d;` instead if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Reallocate as needed.

```
double* data_set = NULL;
int size = 0;
int i = 0;
for(;;) {
    printf("Enter statistical data: ");
    double d;
    // See @Jonathan Leffler for good idea on using blank line to terminate input
    if (1 == scanf("%lf", &d)) {
      break;
    }
    data_set = realloc(data_set, ++size * sizeof(double));
    if (data_set == NULL) handle_error();
    data_set[size-1] = d;
}
*data_size = size;
return data_set;
```